# how can i create a buffer and make syncronize stream

Tags: c++, gstreamer

There is my video streaming example over a network.

When I open the second VlC and stream again video start from the beginning but  I want to make synchronization, for example, The first video is in the 20th.

seconds, the second should start from the 20th second when I open it.
I am working on windows Visual Studio 2017.
How can I deal with this problem?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-media.h>
#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>
#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-media-factory-uri.h>

 #define PORT "8554"
static char *port = (char *)PORT;

static GOptionEntry entries[] = {
{"port",'p', 0, G_OPTION_ARG_STRING, &port,"Port " PORT "", "PORT"}, 
{NULL} };

int main(int argc, gchar * argv[])
{
GMainLoop *loop;
GstRTSPServer *server;
GstRTSPMountPoints *mounts;
GstRTSPMediaFactoryURI *factory;
GOptionContext *sample;
GError *error = NULL;
gchar *uri;

sample = g_option_context_new("<uri> - Test RTSP Server, URI");
g_option_context_add_main_entries(sample, entries, NULL);
g_option_context_add_group(sample, gst_init_get_option_group());
if (!g_option_context_parse(sample, &argc, &argv, &error)) {
    return -1;
}
loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

server = gst_rtsp_server_new();
g_object_set(server, "service", port, NULL);

mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points(server);

factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_uri_new();

const char* streamUri = "https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm";

if (gst_uri_is_valid(streamUri)) {
    uri = g_strdup(streamUri);
}
else if (g_file_test(streamUri, G_FILE_TEST_EXISTS)) {
    uri = gst_filename_to_uri(streamUri, NULL);
}
else {
    printf("There is no uri");
    return -1;
}

gst_rtsp_media_factory_uri_set_uri(factory, uri);
g_free(uri);

gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory(mounts, "/deneme", GST_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY(factory));

g_object_unref(mounts);

if (gst_rtsp_server_attach(server, NULL) == 0)
    printf("FAILED!");

g_print("stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:%s/deneme\n", port);
g_main_loop_run(loop);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the factory as shared, you can do this calling the below function:

```
/* make the factory shared as we will stream same data */
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared(factory, TRUE);
```